# Table of Content not getting Updated in MS Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

As title - I customized the Headings style for a document from 'x' to 'x.x.x.x.x' and used the same. Even after updating my TOC is showing sub headings only upto 'x.x.x' for any section. How do I get that updated till 'x.x.x.x.x'. Please help me. Thanks.

[image: This shows sections till 'x.x.x.x.x']

[image: This shows the corresponding sections names not getting updated in TOC.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too late to help you, but might be useful to someone else:

1. Select all.
2. Right-click on any selected text and click **Toggle Field Codes**. Your ToC should now look something like `{ TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u }`.
3. Change the upper limit from `3` to whatever maximum depth you need, such as `9`.
4. Select all, right-click and select **Toggle Field Codes** again.
5. Update the ToC to pick up the change.